# Выражение должно иметь константное значение

Tags: c, массивы, visual-studio, константа

Visual Studio выдает ошибку "*выражение должно иметь константное значение*" когда задается массив размера N. В чем проблема и как ее решить?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

void generateNums(int *array, int arrayLength) {
   srand(time(NULL));
   for (int i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
       array[i] = rand()%1001;
   }
}

void numsShifting(int *array, int arrayLength) {
   int temp;
   for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
       temp = array[arrayLength - 1];
       for (int i = arrayLength - 1; i > 0; i--) {
           array[i] = array[i - 1];
       }
       array[0] = temp;
   }
}

void printArray(int *array, int arrayLength) {
   for (int i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
       printf("%d\n", array[i]);
   }
}

int main() {
   int N;
   printf("Please write size of array, which you want to shift\n");
   scanf("%d", &N);
   int array[N];
   generateNums(array, N);
   printf("Input array:\n");
   printArray(array, N);
   numsShifting(array, N);
   printf("Result array:\n");
   printArray(array, N);
   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Одну строку изменить

```
scanf("%d", &N);
// Если в строке с `malloc` компилятор без (int)malloc не компилирует -
// значит, на самом деле вы компилируете код как С++, а не как С!!
int * array = malloc(N*sizeof(int));
generateNums(array, N);
printf("Input array:\n");
```

одну добавить

```
printArray(array, N);
free(array);
return 0;
```

Но кроме того, как я понимаю, вы шесть раз пытаетесь выполнить сдвиг на 1 значение? но это по-хорошему делается не так, а двумя разворотами. Конечно, 6 — значение небольшое, ну а если массив в 10000 элемментов и сдвигать на 1000? у вас будет десять миллионо переносов...

Кстати, формально такое можно делать и все у вас в конкретном коде будет работать

```
for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
     temp = array[arrayLength - 1];
     for (int i = arrayLength - 1; i > 0; i--) {
```

но ведь использование одного и того же имени во внешнем и вложенном циклах несколько запутывает, и в более серьезном коде может приводить и к ошибкам...

Comment: Очень благодарен за помощь! И Ваши советы возьму на заметку.

Answer (score 2):

Проблема в компиляторе. Он вам говорит, что размер должен быть фиксирован во время компиляции, то есть вот так: `int array[10];`.

Это требование есть в С++, а в C нет. Разработчикам MSVC чистый C без ++ похоже не очень интересен, и они решили не заморачиваться.

Эту фичу добавили в С99, а после того, как в MSVC не стали добавлять поддержку, стандарт С опять поправили (в С11), и теперь поддержка массивов переменной длины стала необязательной.

Варианты такие:

- Поменять компилятор - на Clang или GCC (которые удобнее всего установить из [MSYS2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30069830/2752075)).
- Использовать `malloc()` - это сложнее.
- Написать размер массива с запасом - несерьезно.
- Перейти на С++ и использовать `std::vector`.